# How to check if a file is on a windows network share?

Tags: c++, windows

I need to check if files are accessed through the network. I'm checking the value of
`GetFileAttributes("\\\\Foo\\Bar\\foobar.txt") & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE` but it's never set. What is the more robust way to achieve this ?

Comment: The offline flag is used to indicate that the file has been relocated to offline storage, e.g., a tape library.  It has nothing to do with networking.

Answer (score 2):

Offline is a special file status that you can also set to on network files but you have to set it yourself. Not every offline file is automatically marked for offline use. I think there even is a special overlay icon on explorer for offline files (a black clock?).

I think that with `PathIsNetworkPath()` you can check that the file is on the network.

Answer (score 1):

call GetVolumePathName and then GetDriveType.

If a network share is specified, GetVolumePathName returns the shortest path for which GetDriveType returns DRIVE_REMOTE.